# print deadlock information in sybase error log

Tags: sybase

How can I print the deadlock info when it occurs in sybase. Specifically I want to know which queries caused a deadlock.

I have read about sp_configure but don't know how to run it ?
http://sybaseblog.com/sybasewiki/index.php?title=How_can_we_print_Deadlock_information_in_errorlog%3F

What prompt is this?

Answer (score 0):

sp_configure "print deadlock information"

That's an sa_role task - is your problem that you don't have sa_role?  Who is the DBA? Get them to do this.  They might mention increased size of the log, but this should not be a problem.

You can find individual deadlocks very easily possibly as long as your client code has logged the time as well, if you've got lots of deadlocking on different things.

You can use perl to scan the log and tabulate.

Or you can use the mda monitoring tables, if you've got them installed.

See sybooks for details of both the above.